# Do computations in F# call Dispose() on completion?

Tags: memory-leaks, f#, idisposable, computation-expression

I have a database connection with a query similar to as follows in a couple separate files in a project:

`SqlTypes.fs`

```
module SqlTypes
open FSharp.Data.TypeProviders

type DBType = SqlDataConnection<ConnectionStrings.DbConnStr>

let getDb() = DBType.GetDataContext() //will this cause a memory leak when called from outside here?
```

`Utilities.fs`

```
module Utilities
open System
open SqlTypes
open System.Linq

///Returns an IQueryable of Orders whose OrderStatus is less than 5 (Not yet released)
let private getOrdersNotYetReleased () =
    let orders = query {
        for order in getDb().Orders do //memleak here?
        where(order.Status < 5)
        sortBy (order.CreatedDateUtc)
        select order
    }
    //return
    orders
```

**Q: Is it necessary to use a `use` clause (like in the following) to prevent a memory leak?**

```
///Returns an IQueryable of Orders whose OrderStatus is less than 5 (Not yet released)
let private getOrdersNotYetReleased () =
    use db = DBType.GetDataContext() //is this safer? Does it matter if this `use` is here?
    let orders = query {
        for order in db.Orders do 
        where(order.Status < 5)
        sortBy (order.CreatedDateUtc)
        select order
    }
    //return
    orders
```

Or, will `Dispose()` be called on the Db object when the computation block exits?

Comment: F# has garbage collection, so the term "memory leak" may not mean what you think it means in this context.

Comment: What would be the appropriate nomenclature here?

Comment: See my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `IDisposable` pattern provides for a `Dispose()` method.  The `use` keyword is there to take advantage of this pattern; if  a class implements `IDisposable`, the author of the class is telling you that using the `use` keyword with their class is probably a good idea.

What the `Dispose()` method actually does depends entirely on what code the author of the class writes for the `Dispose()` method.  There is no guarantee that it even does anything.

Microsoft's official word on `IDisposable` has always been that its purpose is to "clean up unmanaged resources," but in practice, `Dispose()` does whatever the author of the class believes it needs to do to gracefully shut down the object.  What it generally does *not* do is recover memory from managed objects; that is the purpose of the garbage collector.

But, generally speaking, if a class implements `IDisposable`, that means it contains a `Dispose()` method that does something meaningful for the disposition of the object, like closing files or database connections, for example.  So.  Class implements `IDisposable`?  Use `use` with it.

**Further Reading**
[Managing Resources in F#](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/resource-management-the-use-keyword#managing-resources)

Comment: So it's still possible that even when the `query` block exits there can be "unmanaged resources" still lying around (or open connections, etc)?

Comment: Generally, no.  If there are actual "unmanaged resources" being used in a class, and the class is properly written, `Dispose()` will properly clean up those resources.  But it's merely a convention; it still depends on the author of the class doing the right thing with `Dispose()`.

Comment: To be clear, `Dispose()` will *not* be called unless you use the `use` keyword or call it directly.  The whole point of the `use` keyword is to hook up the `IDisposable` machinery so that it will work properly.